# R Studio: Filtering Dataframe not undoable

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to explore my dataset, which is stored in an R dataframe using R Studio. I can filter for the cusip variable by using the built-in filter feature of R Studio as depicted in the screenshot. However, if I delete filter criterium the filter remains active. Basically there is no way to get back to the entire dataset without closing the view and reopening it (which is time consuming for large dataframes (Generally the `View(dataframe)` appears to be slow when files get bigger (3GB+ on my 32GB memory machine)). Any advice on how to do this more efficiently?

[image: R Studio filtering]

Comment: In my case, removing filter criteria works really nice. Maybe it is because of the size of the dataframe. Why you don't try filtering the data using code?

Comment: It would be more efficient using `View(subset(data, cusip == '00030410'))` or `View(data[data$cusip == '00030410', ])`

Comment: @NachoGlez It is quite huge yes. maybe it is because of my Stata background, but I would really prefer to be able to do this in the viewer instead of using code... then again maybe I should just get use to the coding way...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do it in code. For example; Let us assume your original dataframe reference is `df`.

```
df_filtered <- df[df$cusip == '00030410',]
```

Now your `df` is the full dataframe and `df_filtered` is the filtered. Both dataframes will be shown on RStudio viewer.

Comment: maybe it is because I am transitioning from Stata,... but I would really prefer to be able to do some data exploration without using code...